# disabling auxiliary buffers in ESS

Tags: r, emacs, ess

when open an R script in emacs invariably an additional buffer opens up called Flymake Log with the following message

`Warning [flymake DR.R]: Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)`

Following [this discussion](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/883) I added the following line to my `init.el` file:

`(remove-hook 'flymake-diagnostic-functions 'flymake-proc-legacy-flymake)`

but it didn't solve the problem.

Additionally, when I start an R process using `M-x R` an ESS buffer opens up, which says

```
 current-prefix-arg=nil
(inferior-ess: waiting for process to start (before hook)
(inferior-ess 3): waiting for process after hook(R): inferior-ess-language-start=options(STERM='iESS', str.dendrogram.last="'", editor='emacsclient', show.error.locations=TRUE)
```

This happens whenever I restart my R session. It's really annoying and distracting when I constantly have to cycle through these redundant buffers. I say they are redundant, because I haven't noticed any way in which the normal R operation would be disrupted.

I'm using emacs 26.3 with ESS 18.10.3 on ubuntu 20.04 with R 3.6.3. Also, please see below my entire `init.el` file

```
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
    (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "gnu" (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (dracula-theme ess-smart-underscore ess)))
 '(pop-up-windows nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )


;; Makes *scratch* empty.
(setq initial-scratch-message "")

;; Removes *scratch* from buffer after the mode has been set.
(defun remove-scratch-buffer ()
  (if (get-buffer "*scratch*")
      (kill-buffer "*scratch*")))
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'remove-scratch-buffer)

;; Removes *messages* from the buffer.
(setq-default message-log-max nil)
(kill-buffer "*Messages*")

;; Removes *Completions* from buffer after you've opened a file.
(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (let ((buffer "*Completions*"))
           (and (get-buffer buffer)
                (kill-buffer buffer)))))

;; Don't show *Buffer list* when opening multiple files at the same time.
(setq inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)

;; Show only one active window when opening multiple files at the same time.
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'delete-other-windows)

;; backup in one place. flat, no tree structure
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . "~/.emacs.d/backup")))

;; easier switching between windows
(windmove-default-keybindings 'control)

;; color theme
(load-theme 'dracula t)

;; matching parenthesis
(show-paren-mode 1)


;; keybindings for resizing windows
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<left>") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<right>") 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<down>") 'shrink-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<up>") 'enlarge-window)

;; easier switching between buffers
(ido-mode 1)

;; no menu bar
(menu-bar-mode -1)

;; no line wrapping by default
(set-default 'truncate-lines t)

;; Disable Flymake warnings
(remove-hook 'flymake-diagnostic-functions 'flymake-proc-legacy-flymake)

;; disables ESS buffer
(setq ess-write-to-dribble t)
```

The last line was an attempt at permanently disabling the ESS log buffer.